# Не работает функция header

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Есть 2 файла
`C:\WebServers\home\my_shop1\www\admin\login.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Вход в административную зону</title>
</head>

<body>
<div style:"width:350px; margin:0 auto; border:#000 thick solid; margin-top: 40px">
<form action="login_save.php" method="post">
<label>Введите логин</label><br/>
<input name="users_login" type="text" /><br/>
<label>Введите пароль</label><br/>
<input name="users_password" type="password" /><br/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="вход в админ зону" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

и `C:\WebServers\home\my_shop1\www\admin\login.php`

```
<?php
    include_once('blocks/bd.php'); 
    session_start();
    if ($_POST)
    {
        $users_login=$_POST['users_login'];
        $users_password=$_POST['users_password'];

        $users_login=mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($users_login)));  
        $users_password=mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($users_password)));

        $sql_user = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE users_login='$users_login' AND users_password='$users_password'";
        $query_user=mysql_query($sql_user) or die(mysql_error());       
        $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_user);
    }
        header('Location: ../index.php');

?>
```

и есть также файл `C:\WebServers\home\my_shop1\www\index.php`, на который не перебрасывает функция header после успешного ввода пароля и перехода со страницы login на login_save.php. В чем причина?

Comment: @ivan89 `login_save.php` укажите. А то у вас два файла `login.php` :)

Comment: есть предположение, что включение вывода ошибок поможет решить эту мистику :)

Comment: @thunder, +1

Comment: еще я бы порекомендовал сохранить файлы в UTF-8 without BOM, это обычно именно та проблема, которая непозволяет нормально работать header под виндами :)

Comment: @thunder, а под линуксом ``UTF-8 с BOM`` не мешает ``header``'ам?

Comment: точно не скажу, но поидее мешает, я давно все файлы в utf-8 w/o BOM перевел :) мой коммент написан про данный конкретный случай, так как судя по путям "мистика" происходит под виндой.

Answer (score 2):

1. Сохранить файлы в UTF-8 без BOM
2. Возможно вот тут `include_once('blocks/bd.php');` есть какой-то вывод.
3. Еще вариант: `$query_user=mysql_query($sql_user) or die(mysql_error());`  тут происходит ошибка